# Is there a way to get elements of a data frame where the index elements match the elements of a list

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, filter

Lets say we have a data frame that looks like this

| Index 1 | Index 2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | z | 1 |
| a | z | 2 |
| b | y | 1 |
| c | y | 1 |

And I have a list `list = [c,a,d]`
Note that the list might have index values which are not in the data frame.
Is there a way how I can access all the rows from the data frame for the indexes where is matches with the list?
So in this example the output would look like this:

| Index 1 | Index 2 | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | z | 1 |
| a | z | 2 |
| c | y | 1 |

Comment: There’s no `index 2` column in your output − is that expected ?

Comment: No, thats a mistake. Will correct it now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`MultiIndex.get_level_values`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.MultiIndex.get_level_values.html) with [`Index.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.isin.html), `loc` is not necessary here:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values('Index 1').isin(['c', 'a', 'd'])]
```

Answer (score 4):

[pd.Series.isin()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) tests if elements are part of a list (or set), which returns a boolean Series. You can combine that with [`pd.DataFrame.loc[]`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) which accepts such a boolean series.

This combination will not throw an error when elements of the list are not part of the index, as opposed to using `.loc[list]` directly.

```py
>>> df.loc[df['Index 1'].isin(['c', 'a', 'd'])]
  Index 1 Index 2  Value
0       a       z      1
1       a       z      2
3       c       y      1
```

Comment: df['Index 1'] is not working though, but `df.loc[df.index.get_level_values('Index 1').isin([c, a, d])]` solved the problem for me

Comment: @youneedtoread1 - just type in my answer ;)

Comment: @youneedtoread1 Not easy to see which columns were indexes indeed. But `isin()` exists for indexes as well, as @jezrael has shown